# how to make the annotation move over the polyline

Tags: swift, mapkit, direction

i have 3 annotation and i draw polyline between first and second annotation but i need the therd one move over that polyline but it's always move in street polyline to the destnation

-my code

```
   func moveDelivery(_ destinationCoordinate : CLLocationCoordinate2D{
        self.deliveryAnnotation.coordinate =      CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.959640, 31.270421)
    let sourcePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate:     self.userAnnotation.coordinate)
    //sourcePlaceMark.title
    let destPlaceMkark = MKPlacemark(coordinate:   self.deliveryAnnotation.coordinate)

    let sourceItem = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlaceMark)
    let destItem = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlaceMkark)

    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.source = sourceItem
    directionRequest.destination = destItem
    directionRequest.transportType = .any

    let direction = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    direction.calculate(completionHandler: {
        response, error in
        guard let response = response else {

            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.deliveryAnnotation.courseDegrees =   self.getHeadingForDirectionFromCoordinate(self.kitchenAnnotation.coordinate, toLoc: self.userAnnotation.coordinate)
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat(self.deliveryAnnotation.courseDegrees))
            }
            return
        }
        guard let primaryRoute = response.routes.first else { return }
        let route = response.routes[0]
        self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

        let rekt = route.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rekt), animated: true)

    })

    //
    UIView.animate(withDuration: Double(60), animations: {

        self.deliveryAnnotation.coordinate = destinationCoordinate

    }, completion:  { success in
        if success {

        }
    })
}
```

[image: ScreenShot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your third annotation isn't following the route because you're animating it moving in a straight line between the first and second line. Try getting the coordinates from the MKRoute's polyline and animate between each one (According to apple's docs MKRoutes are made up of coordinates, but you might be able to use points as well)

If you'd like it to animate over the span of 60 seconds:

```
func moveDelivery(_ destinationCoordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

    // I don't know why you have the delivery annotation start here, is this for testing?
    deliveryAnnotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.959640, 31.270421)

    let sourcePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: destinationCoordinate)
    let destPlaceMkark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: userAnnotation.coordinate)

    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlaceMark)
    directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlaceMkark)
    directionRequest.transportType = .any
    let direction = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

    direction.calculate(completionHandler: {
        response, error in
        guard let response = response else {
            print("MKRequest gave no response")
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else {
                self.deliveryAnnotation.courseDegrees =   self.getHeadingForDirectionFromCoordinate(self.kitchenAnnotation.coordinate, toLoc: self.userAnnotation.coordinate)
                self.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle:CGFloat(self.deliveryAnnotation.courseDegrees))
            }

            return
        }

        guard let primaryRoute = response.routes.first else {
            print("response has no routes")
            return
        }

        self.mapView.addOverlay(primaryRoute.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)

        let rekt = primaryRoute.polyline.boundingMapRect
        self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(rekt), animated: true)

        let coordinateArray = primaryRoute.polyline.coordinates

        assert(coordinateArray.count > 0, "coordinate array is empty")

        self.routeCoordinates = coordinateArray

        // initiate recursive animations
        self.coordinateIndex = 0
    })

}

var routeCoordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

var avgAnimationTime: Double {
    return 60 / Double(routeCoordinates.count)
}

var coordinateIndex: Int! {
    didSet {
        guard coordinateIndex != routeCoordinates.count else {
            print("animated through all coordinates, stopping function")
            return
        }

        animateToNextCoordinate()
    }
}

func animateToNextCoordinate() {
    let coordinate = routeCoordinates[coordinateIndex]

    UIView.animate(withDuration: avgAnimationTime, animations: {
        self.deliveryAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
    }, completion:  { _ in
        self.coordinateIndex += 1
        print("moved between coordinates")
    })
}
```

**EDIT**

make sure to include this extension, otherwise you won't be able to get the coordinates of the MKRoute (source: https://gist.github.com/freak4pc/98c813d8adb8feb8aee3a11d2da1373f)

```
public extension MKMultiPoint {
    var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](repeating: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid,
                                              count: pointCount)

        getCoordinates(&coords, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: pointCount))

        return coords
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2**

See above, edited original answer to animate through each coordinate after the previous finishes animating. Really rough but it should work.

**EDIT #3**

Added your code to get the `destination` variable as well as some assert and debug printing calls. If things aren't working this time, please tell me which debug messages you get.

**EDIT #4**

I just demo'd my code and it works. Here is the `MapViewController` class I used along with necessary extensions:

[image: Demo_gif]

```
private let reuseId = "deliveryReuseId"

private let userTitle = "user"
private let startingPointTitle = "store"
private let deliveryTitle = "delivery truck"

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView: MKMapView!

    // annotations for this demo, replace with your own annotations
    var deliveryAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = deliveryTitle

        return annotation
    }()

    let userAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = userTitle
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.956694, 31.276854)
        return annotation
    }()

    let startingPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation = {
        let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
        annotation.title = startingPointTitle
        annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(29.959622, 31.270363)
        return annotation
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        loadMapView()
        navigate()
    }

    func loadMapView() {
        // set map
        mapView = MKMapView()
        view = mapView
        mapView.delegate = self
        mapView.register(MKAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: reuseId)

        // add annotations
        mapView.addAnnotation(userAnnotation)
        mapView.addAnnotation(startingPointAnnotation)
        mapView.addAnnotation(deliveryAnnotation)
    }

    func navigate() {
        let sourcePlaceMark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: startingPointAnnotation.coordinate)
        let destPlaceMkark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: userAnnotation.coordinate)

        let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
        directionRequest.source = MKMapItem(placemark: sourcePlaceMark)
        directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destPlaceMkark)
        directionRequest.transportType = .any

        let direction = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)

        direction.calculate(completionHandler: { response, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)

                return
            }

            guard let primaryRoute = response!.routes.first else {
                print("response has no routes")
                return
            }

            self.mapView.addOverlay(primaryRoute.polyline, level: .aboveRoads)
            self.mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegion(primaryRoute.polyline.boundingMapRect), animated: true)

            // initiate recursive animation
            self.routeCoordinates = primaryRoute.polyline.coordinates
            self.coordinateIndex = 0
        })
    }

    var routeCoordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

    var avgAnimationTime: Double {
        // to show delivery in 60 second, replace 60 with amount of seconds you'd like to show
        return 60 / Double(routeCoordinates.count)
    }

    var coordinateIndex: Int! {
        didSet {
            guard coordinateIndex != routeCoordinates.count else {
                print("animated through all coordinates, stopping function")
                return
            }

            animateToNextCoordinate()
        }
    }

    func animateToNextCoordinate() {
        let coordinate = routeCoordinates[coordinateIndex]

        UIView.animate(withDuration: avgAnimationTime, animations: {
            self.deliveryAnnotation.coordinate = coordinate
        }, completion:  { _ in
            self.coordinateIndex += 1
        })
    }
}

extension MapViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        let annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)

        // replace these images with your own
        switch annotation.title {
        case userTitle:
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "user")
        case startingPointTitle:
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "store")
        case deliveryTitle:
            annotationView.image = UIImage(named: "deliveryTruck")
        default: break
        }

        return annotationView
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

        guard overlay is MKPolyline else {
            return MKOverlayRenderer()
        }

        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = .black
        renderer.lineWidth = 5
        renderer.lineJoin = .round

        return renderer
    }
}

public extension MKMultiPoint {
    var coordinates: [CLLocationCoordinate2D] {
        var coords = [CLLocationCoordinate2D](repeating: kCLLocationCoordinate2DInvalid,
                                              count: pointCount)

        getCoordinates(&coords, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: pointCount))

        return coords
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for replay Wilson i tried you solution but the annotation stop and not moving in the start point

Comment: @HamadaRaouf sorry, my code isn't right, it initiates each animation before the next is done so that's probably why the annotation isn't going anywhere. I'll edit it now to run recursively

Comment: @HamadaRaouf please see my edit, it's pretty hacked together but now it should animate correctly. Double check that the `coordinateArray` variable is being set and that you're including that extension I listed at the bottom of my answer. Let me know if you're still having problems and I can look at it again.

Comment: thank you so much Wilson so now i have to call getDirection() to start move the annotation ? because it's not moving when i call this func i appreciate  what r u trying to do thank you so much

Comment: @HamadaRaouf yes, just make sure to replace my `direction` variable with your own given it's a blank placeholder (I'll add an edit to my answer based on what you wrote in your original post).

Comment: @HamadaRaouf I've amended my post to include your code to get the `direction` variable. I switched the source and destination variables (because I'm assuming you're trying to animate to the user from the destination). If it doesn't work this time, could you tell me which print messages you get in the debugger? Do you know how much of the function it gets through? If it makes it to the animation section it should animate correctly. Also can you confirm you're including the `MKMultipoint` extension?

Comment: @HamadaRaouf lol sorry to keep commenting, but I added a demo of my code. Please let me know if you have any questions, otherwise please accept my answer as correct if it works for you.

Comment: Wow thank you man sooo much it's awesome answer i apperciate that too much